# Using .NET ArrayList .RemoveAt() does not recalculate count right

Tags: .net, vb.net, arraylist

I am using an `ArrayList` in VB.Net which is being filled with 300+ records. As I process them I remove the record at a specified Index, because they are not stored in order. My problem is when I first look at the count of the `Arraylist` before I use `RemoveAt()` the count says 373, but after using `RemoveAt()` a couple of time I noticed the count to go up around 425.

From my understanding of the MSDN reference pages for `ArrayList.RemoveAt()`, the method should remove the element at the specified index and decrease the `ArrayList` count by one.

If anyone has run into this problem or have any clue as to why it's doing this please let me know.

**Update** each element in the arraylist is an instance of an object.

**Update** this is the code that finds an element in the arraylist to extract and then remove it.

```
    While (SimsRun.Count > 0)

        counter = 0

        'Get a new record
        While (counter < SimsRun.Count)

            tempSim = SimsRun(counter)

            If tempSim.BatchIndex = (simToFind - 1) Then

                SimsRun.RemoveAt(counter)

                Exit While

            End If

            counter = counter + 1

        End While

        Process Record
        .
        .
        .
        .

    End While
```

The outer loop that this is in will run while SimsRun.Count() > 0.

Comment: This should not happen (unless something else is adding elements).  Can you show code that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: need an SSCCE (http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: Well the program is so complex that i couldn't send just the spot that will show it. But i can include the part of the code that removes the element at the specified location. Anymore questions let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related to your issue, but you are counting up from zero and removing objects, then incrementing your counter. By doing this you are effectively skipping every other item in your list. If you have 4 elements, and you remove item 0, and counter = 0, then the next item you want to check is item 0, not item 1, as you have removed item 0 and what was item 1 is now item 0. Make sense? You either need to change how you handle your counter variable or start from the end of the array and count down. As far as having too many items at the end, just throw in a Debug.WriteLine that prints out your array count as you move along, and you should see the count go down, not up. If the array is growing, then you have code you haven't posted that is causing this.

Comment: this loop goes off when i want to find a particular record in the batch file. once found it is processed and then it returns to this loop where counter is initilized back to zero and then starts the search again. Sorry i forgot to include the counter initilizer before the loop.